# postgres partiton char - values from to inclusive

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, sharding

Hello I have a tables called agents thats partitoned on `name`
Now I want to create a horizontal partitoning for names starting from g to z.
the problem that when I do like the below code piece names like 'zizo' dont find a table since the to statement is exclusive.
Also How to make it case insensitive??

```sql
CREATE TABLE agents_gz
PARTITION OF agents
FOR VALUES FROM ('^g') TO ('^z');
```

Comment: If the expression `FOR VALUES FROM ...TO ...` accepts regular expressions (not found in the manual), then you can try this : `FOR VALUES FROM ('^(g|G)') TO ('^(zz|ZZ)')`

Comment: @EdouardH. Thanks. Do you know how to partition based on ints? like `from (100) to infinity` ?  Do you know how to do this in postgres?

Comment: `FROM (100) TO (MAXVALUE)` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could define the partition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE agents_gz
PARTITION OF agents
FOR VALUES FROM ('g') TO (MAXVALUE);
```

Specifying `'^g'` will only work accidentally, because many collations ignore special characters when comparing strings.  But using `'g'` as the lower bound is better.

For the upper bound you can use `MAXVALUE`, which means that the upper bound is defined as the maximum possible string.